# Select all CheckBoxes not working inside a webgrid Jquery and ASP.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox, bulk

I need to select all checkboxes in my table and also I need to select each rowas separately. To achive that I used this [post](http://demo.dotnetawesome.com/webgrid/selecting-deselecting-all-checkboxes-inside-webgrid-mvc4) .

This is Jquery Code

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // 1st replace first column header text with checkbox

            $("#checkableGrid th").each(function () {               
                if ($.trim($(this).text().toString().toLowerCase()) === "{checkall}") {
                    $(this).text('');
                    $("<input/>", { type: "checkbox", id: "cbSelectAll", value: "" }).appendTo($(this));
                    $(this).append("<span>Select All</span>");
                }
            });

            //2nd click event for header checkbox for select /deselect all
            $("#cbSelectAll").live("click", function () {
                var ischecked = this.checked;
                $('#checkableGrid').find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                    this.checked = ischecked;
                });
            });


            //3rd click event for checkbox of each row
            $("input[name='ids']").click(function () {
                var totalRows = $("#checkableGrid td :checkbox").length;
                var checked = $("#checkableGrid td :checkbox:checked").length;

                if (checked == totalRows) {
                    $("#checkableGrid").find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
                        this.checked = true;
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $("#cbSelectAll").removeAttr("checked");
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
}
```

And I call it like this,

```
<div>
    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "gridtable",
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "checkableGrid" },
    columns: grid.Columns
        (
    //Here I am going to add checkbox column
            grid.Column(
                format: @<text> <input type="checkbox" value="@item.CustomerID" name="ids" /> </text>,
                header: "{checkall}"
            ),
            grid.Column("CustomerID", "Customer ID"),
            grid.Column("CustomerName", "Customer Name"),
            grid.Column("Address", "Address"),
            grid.Column("City", "City"),
            grid.Column("PostalCode", "Postal Code")
        )
    )
</div>
```

Each row can select separately, but I can't select all the rows at one time. The `Select All` check box not showing,instead of that its showing as `{checkall}`

[image]

Please someone help me to solve this.
Thank you.

Comment: You're not really using jQuery to it's full potential, I suggest [Learn jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/).  Your setter should just be `$('#checkableGrid input:checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));`

Comment: Are your grid rows inserted/deleted from the DOM *after* the dom loads?  If not there is no reason to use `live()` which really should just be `on()` (because version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9, no reason to write obsolete code).

Comment: @Erik Philips Sir please give me the complete answer if you can. I'm really stacked with this.please

Comment: I don't know what your html output is.

Comment: @Erik Philips I did same as that post(tutorial) . db table loads to grid. and each row can select separately, but all select checkbox not showing,instead of that its shows as `{checkall}` like this image https://i.imgur.com/JWyR4Rx.png

Comment: **please post the generated html**.

Comment: @Erik Philips what do you mean by generated html? I did same as the that post

Comment: the code between `<div>` and `</div>` on a web browser is not what is posted.  I'm not trying to be rude, but are you fairly new to web development?

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` event instead of `click` and write as follows:

```
//2nd click event for header checkbox for select /deselect all

$(document).on('change', '#cbSelectAll', function () {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('#checkableGrid').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
  } else {
     $('#checkableGrid').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: But still not appear checkbox in header row to check all rows, still there have `{checkall}`

Comment: oh! understood! Your header checkbox is missing!

Comment: yes :( can you help me to solve this, please check this http://demo.dotnetawesome.com/webgrid/selecting-deselecting-all-checkboxes-inside-webgrid-mvc4 
I did according to this post,

Comment: Can you give me team viewer id and pass?

Comment: Oops, I'm working on university PC. I cannot install any S/W,

Comment: oh! Sorry! Okay Let me check more details what wrong actually

Comment: There is no reason for the if statement.